# var in c# to support either Type1 or Type2

Tags: c#, generics, types, var

I have two auto-generated classes, say Type1 and Type2. Each of these classes deals with other related auto-generated classes. Since they are auto-generated, I cannot change them to use either abstract classes or interfaces.
I have two methods, one return Type1 and the other return Type2. Type1 and Type2 are almost the same, so I wanted to call them like below to avoid code duplication on my side, of course it did not work as the type needs to be known in compile time.

```
var response = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputObject.HistoricYear) ? Type1: Type2;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputObject.HistoricYear))
{
    response = TsiService.GetAccountTransactionsList(inputObject);
} else
{
    response = TsiService.GetAccountTransactionsHist(inputObject);
}
```

I also tried using `object` and then I get this error `object does not contain a definition for MEMBER_1 and MEMBER_2, etc.`:

```
var response = null;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputObject.HistoricYear))
{
    response = TsiService.GetAccountTransactionsList(inputObject);
} else
{
    response = TsiService.GetAccountTransactionsHist(inputObject);
}

CustomObject.member1 = response.MEMBER_1;
CustomObject.member2 = response.MEMBER_2;
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean: "it did not work"? Are you getting any error?

Comment: `var` cannot be used with different types depending on some condition. The type should be known at compile time. You can rewrite your code a bit - `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputObject.HistoricYear)) { /* use Type1 */ } else { /* use Type2 */ }` and make `response` of `object` type

Comment: @McNets I get this error and it makes sense but I wanted to know if there is a way to do so without repetition: `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between`

Comment: @Sherzad, you can change `var response` to `object response` but I assume later you'll need a casting.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch currently I do. As I mentioned, `Type1` and `Type2` are almost identical and I wanted to avoid processing their members separately. I wanted to know if there is a way to make the `response` global and only process the members once for both.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch I already tried `object`, same issue.

Comment: If you can't make the common parts of the response into an interface then map/convert the types to something common that you can actually use afterwards. As said before you could use object type or do bad things with dynamic. But it the end it just prevents doing the right thing. Either change the generator that it creates something useful by using interfaces for example or map the response to a common type afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical solution would be to make sure that both `Type1` and `Type2` implement a common interface defining `MEMBER_1`, `MEMBER_2`, etc.

Since you cannot do that for technical reasons, you have two options:

1. Create *wrapper* types: Create a new class `Type1WithInterface`, which has the same members as `Type1`, but also implements that common interface described above. `Type1WithInterfaces` gets a `Type1` instance in its constructor and passes every property access to the underlying `Type1`.
2. Alternatively, you can use the [`dynamic` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic). It disables compile-time type checks for member accesses.

The drawback of option 1 is that you will have to write a lot of boiler-plate code, but the advantage is that you will retain type safety. With option 2, all type safety bets are off, and typos will bite you at run-time rather than at compile-time.